# I am planning to design comparator based on Opamp but I am not getting the exact pulse output in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, pulse, single-supply-op-amp

[image: OPAMP COMPARAOTR CIRCUIT DIAGRAM]

[image: LTSPICE OUTPUT]

[image: Expected pulse output]

I am trying to simulate this but I am not getting the exact "RECTANGULR" pulse output. Kindly help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

I am going to use this circuit as pulse generator for gating MOSFET.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You've set the peak of your triangle wave to 4 V with a minimum of 0 V. And you've set the comparison threshold to 3 V. That's not going to be 50%. You've also done nothing about hysteresis, which you probably should. But that's a separate issue. What, precisely, do you expect to get?

Comment: "..comparator based on opamp.." Actually that LT1017 **is** a comparator, not an opamp. There is no opamp in your circuit.

Comment: Vengatesh - I'd be tempted to reopen this question BUT it seems that the answers that  you have received  answer your question adequately/ Are you happy with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LT1017 is a micropower comparator, not an opamp. Micropower should clue you in that it is probably slow and not suitable for the input signal timing you are using. You will get better results if you use a pull-up resistor since the built-in pull up current is under 100 uA (pretty low for your requirements).

You will be better off using a faster comparator like the LT1720 (about 100x faster than the LT1017 and included in the LTspice library) or something like the LMV7239 (about 10x times faster than the LT1017, but you'll need to import the PSpice model).

You may want to include some hysteresis to improve noise resistance.

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting corresponds to what the datasheet says. In fact the simulation results are quite optimistic regarding speed.

[image]

If you want to do 100kHz PWM with a comparator, you'll need a much faster one, here's [an example](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6561-1R-1U-2-4-1.8V-Low-Power-Push-Pull-Output-Comparator-DS20002139E.pdf).